# autocomplete in gvim for ruby

Tags: vim

It is possible to setting up autocomplete menu in gvim?
For example in ruby file, when I type a name of object, `object1.<C-P>`, I want to see attributes and methods of this object1, but vim load in menu all words from file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<C-p>` and `<C-n>` complete with words in the active buffers.

`<C-x><C-o>` completes methods and properties.

`<C-x><C-l>` completes whole lines.

`<C-x><C-f>` completes file names.

```
:help ins-completion
```